# C# + NUnit3 + need the list of classes selected for execution to send mail after last class execution

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

Used Tools: NUnit3 Test Adapter, NUnit3 Lib & Visual Studio 2019

OneTimeSetup & OneTimeTeardown attribute function are class level functions so when I call send mail function from this it works good for single TestFixture class.

When I select multiple Test Fixture classes for single execution, Nunit move to OneTimeTeardown attribute function for every class execution and send multiple Email reports

To Solve this issue, I need list of Test Fixture classes I have selected for current execution and this information is not provide by CurrentTestContext

stack overflow site provide solution which we need to start NUnit execution from Code but I am using NUnit3 Test Adapter to trigger execution and I need this information at runtime.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: [SetupFixture](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/setupfixture.html) allows you to specify  OneTimeSetup & OneTimeTeardown methods at the execution level, i.e. once for all fixture classes selected for execution. Does that help?